# svn - rolled back a commit now I want to restore that commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I committed some code to trunk, lets say revision number 499.  I tested the result and wasn't entirely happy, I then did a revert using merge from command line inside the working copy

```
svn merge -c -499 .
```

This worked fine, after retesting my code I realised there wasn't an issue with the commit, so I want to restore the code, I can see from looking at the file it has pre 499 code, I tried the following but didn't work

```
svn merge -c 499 .
```

I'm never using svn enough in the context of reverting / restoring commits, I searched online but nothing really fits my query, I know it'll be something really easy but struggling to find it.

Edit: should have said that the changes are in the repository

Comment: In the future you should adopt a workflow that doesn't involve history changes when hunting down bugs. You could've just as easily updated to an older changeset and retested your code there, without merging or doing anything to your repository history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to fix this depends on whether or not you have used `svn commit` to send your merge to the repository.

The best scenario is if you have not yet committed your changes. `svn merge` only affects your working copy, so undoing that merge is as easy as `svn revert`. Then your working copy will match what is in your repository.

If you already committed the changes to revert revision 499, things are a little more complicated because you need to undo a change in the *repository*. For the sake of example, assume this revert was committed as revision 500. You want to go back to revision 499, so what you want is to remove the changes from revision 500:

```
svn merge -c -500 .
```

In other words, "revert the revert commit". Then commit that change to push it out to everyone.

Comment: my revert (svn merge -c -499 .) did not create a new revision number though

Comment: Ok so it hasn't hit the server yet. Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks, this makes sense to me now, I didn't do an svn commit after the svn merge so it was only my working copy that was affected and not the repository.  I now know how to handle both scenarios :)

Answer (score 1):

ok so searching online looking for some more data on my problem, I resolved it using the following code, may not be the cleanest way of solving it but it worked for me

```
svn merge -r HEAD:499 .
```

that brought up a confict so I choose tf (theirs full) to restore the file back to revision 499

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you did:

> You created a new *revision*. This revision has a set of changes that you made just like every other revision. The change may have rolled back your changes in previous revisions, but in the end, it's just another Subversion revision.

How do you get rid of a revision you no longer want? You do a *reverse merge* just like you did to get rid of other changes you don't want.

To rollback a rollback, simply do a reverse merge of that particular revision:

```
$ svn log -r503
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
r503 | user2751034 | 2015-03-05 13:37:48 -0500 (Thu, 05 Mar 2015) | X lines
Rolled back change in revision 400
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, you backed out Revision 400 in Revision 503. (And, that's why we do good, detailed commit comments!)

So, to undo the change that undid your change in Revision 400...

```
$ svn merge -c -503 .
```

And, now the changes you made in revision 400 are back in the repository!